# Hash of object changes before and after retrieving from Python shelf

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, hash, persistence, networkx

## The issue

I generate a `chimera` graph, which is basically a `dwave_networkx` object. `dwave_networkx` inherits from the `networkx` graph class. I store this in a Python shelf. The hash of the original graph and the one retrieved from the shelf are different, and I can't figure out why. I require both to be the same.

## Code

```
import dwave_networkx as dnx
import shelve
```

```
def generate_graph(N):

    graph = dnx.chimera_graph(1, N, 4)
    graph_id = ""
   
    for node in graph.nodes:
        graph.nodes[node]['weight'] = _get_node_weight() # A function that returns a random number
    for edge in graph.edges:
        graph.edges[edge]['weight'] = _get_edge_weight() # A function that returns a random number
    
    graph_id = str(hash(graph))
    return graph, graph_id
```

```
shelf = shelve.open("graphs.shelf")
ids = []

for i in range(10):
    graph, id = generate_graph(5)
    ids.append(id)
    shelf[id] = {"graph": graph}

for i in ids:
    print(i, hash(shelf[i]["graph"])

# The two values in each row turn out to be different!

shelf.close()
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because of the fact that the `shelf` object is basically creating a copy of the original graph. See this example:

```
shelf = shelve.open("dummy.shelf")

# List are mutable, just like the Graphs
x = [1, 2, 3]

# Add the the list to shelf
shelf["1"] = x

print(id(x), id(shelf["1"]))
# 5314942976 5314799232

shelf.close()
```

As you can see, a copy of the original list is created and add to shelf (Similar to what is happening to the Graphs as they are mutable classes). You can take a look at the [implementation here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/shelve.py#L119) for more information.

**References:**

- [Python Shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html)